# Can I weaken the minimum degree hypothesis in Nash-Williams' triangle decomposition conjecture?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

In what follows, all graphs $G$ are $K_3$-divisible (all degrees even, number of edges a multiple of three) on $n$ vertices, where $n$ is not too small.

The famous Nash-Williams conjecture claims that $\delta(G) \ge \frac{3}{4}n$ would be sufficient for $G$ to have a $K_3$-decomposition of its edges.  (The constant is asymptotically sharp and Gustavsson's theorem answers in the affirmative with $\frac{3}{4}$ replaced by $1-10^{-24}$.)

To my untrained eye, this hypothesis on minimum degree has always seemed stronger than necessary.  I am interested in weakening the hypotheses in the following direction.

> If $\delta(G) > c n$ and $|E(G)|> \frac{3}{4}\binom{n}{2}$ then $G$
>   has a triangle decomposition.

(That is, if the minimum degree of $G$ is *not too small* while the *average* degree is at least what Nash-Williams demands, then we still have a $K_3$-decomposition.)

I can make silly counterexamples for $c \lesssim 3/28$.  Just take a $K_3$-divisible but non-$K_3$-decomposable graph on $m$ vertices which is $\lesssim 3/4$-dense and disjoint union with a clique of order $6 m+1$.  The resulting graph has $n=7m+1$ vertices, minimum degree about $3n/28$, and average density $\gtrsim (3/4+6^2)/7^2 = 3/4$.

Why would one want to make a hard conjecture even harder?  I suppose it is just an attempt to understand what really *makes* it hard!

So here comes my MO question.  **Are there any obvious counterexamples to the above for** $\frac{3}{28} < c < \frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed the following for $c = 1/2$:  Take a complete graph of even order $n$ and remove a spanning disjoint union of two stars, say centered at vertices $x$ and $y$.  Remove a few more edges for $K_3$-divisibility.  Then (1) the average degree is near $n$; (2) the minimum degree is $n/2$ (when the two stars are balanced); and (3) edge $e = \{x,y\}$ belongs to no triangle.  Can $c$ be pushed even higher than $1/2$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you divide the vertex set into 3 parts, A, B and C, with respective sizes $an$, $bn$ and $cn$, and add all the edges except the ones connecting two vertices inside A and a vertex from A and C, then you get a graph with $\delta=bn$ and $|E|=(1-{a^2}-2ac) {n\choose 2}$. If $b<a$, you won't have a triangle-decomposition as for any 2 edges between A and B you need an edge inside B but there aren't enough. If $a=b$, then $c=1-2a$ and $|E|=(1+3{a^2}-2a) {n\choose 2}$, solving which to get $\frac 34{n\choose 2}$ edges we get that $a=\frac 12$ or $\frac 16$. As you've noted of the former in your comment, it can only give slightly less than $\frac 34{n\choose 2}$ edges, so we gotto go with $a=b=\frac 16$ and $c=\frac 23$ which gives (your) $c=\frac 16$.

I am not sure if you can also achieve $\frac 34$ with a similar example but I would not be surprised.

Comment: Oops, good points, I had covering the vertices with triangles in mind. But miraculously almost the same construction works for your problem!

Comment: In this new construction, if you carefully count $|E|$ you will find it is less than $\frac{3}{4} \binom{n}{2}$.  (I believe I have tried all of these obvious things, but I could be wrong.)  I would not be surprised to see counterexamples for $c$ a little bigger than $3/28$, but I would be very surprised to see an example with "large" $c$.

Comment: Thank you.  This one seems to be a winner at $c=1/6$.  It is actually quite similar to my example at $c=3/28$, except that the union is not a *disjoint* union and so you can reduce my "6".  Btw, are you still claiming $3/4$ would not surprise you?  It sure would surprise me!

Comment: Indeed, 3/4 is farther from 1/6 than 2/3, but I still think that it might be possible to somehow blow-up a small counterexample in a clever way.